# How to put a UIView in a UITableView

Tags: uiview, uitableview

I have a UITableView and I'm trying to put a graph in my table above the cells. I have a "GraphView" that I've made that extends UIView and I'd like to put it in my table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set it as the `tableHeaderView`, like so:

```
UITableView *tv = ...;

tv.tableHeaderView = yourView;
```

or using Interface Builder, even easier.

Read the documentation of `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` to find out more about these functions:

```
 -(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 -(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

You should then return a `UIView` per section. (remember to `autorelease` them, if they are not statically allocated!)

Comment: but I'd like a uiview at the top of each section in my uitableview. how can I do this?

Comment: will this remove the title bars for each section?

Comment: You will be providing the entire section header, indeed replacing the title bars you probably have now. But what you could do, if you're lazy, is to put an empty section above every section just to get the original title bar there.

Comment: okay, good idea. Now what about setting the size of the title? Because my view I have is larger than the normal size of the title.

Comment: The header will be as big as you make it. Just return a `UIView` with the height you want it to have.