# Adding a UIView to a UITableViewCell via cell.contentView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a class called GraphView that extends UIView that basically draws a small little line chart. I need one of these graphs at the top of each section in my UITableView. So I tried by creating a separate cell at the top of one of my sections and then on that cell I did:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:graphView];
[graphView release];
```

But when I scroll down, it's like the graph is glitchy and it shows up in random spots along the UITableView. Anyone have ideas or insight? Is there a better way to incorporate another UIView into the top of each section in my UITableView?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //NSLog(@"cellForrowAtIndexPath");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];


    NSString *str1, *str2;
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        if(indexPath.row == 0) {

            str1 = @"";
            str2 = @"";

            S7GraphView *graphView = [[S7GraphView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,310,100)];
            graphView.dataSource = self;

            NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
            [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
            [numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
            [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];

            graphView.yValuesFormatter = numberFormatter;

            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
            [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
            [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

            graphView.xValuesFormatter = dateFormatter;

            [dateFormatter release];        
            [numberFormatter release];

            graphView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            graphView.drawAxisX = NO;
            graphView.drawAxisY = YES;
            graphView.drawGridX = NO;
            graphView.drawGridY = YES;

            graphView.xValuesColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            graphView.yValuesColor = [UIColor blackColor];

            graphView.gridXColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            graphView.gridYColor = [UIColor blackColor];

            graphView.drawInfo = NO;
            graphView.info = @"Load";
            graphView.infoColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


            //When you need to update the data, make this call:

            //[graphView reloadData];

            //S7GraphView *graphView = [[S7GraphView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,320,300)];
            //self.graphView.dataSource = self;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:graphView];
            [graphView release];
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put a UIView in a UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575410/how-to-put-a-uiview-in-a-uitableview)

Comment: @Robert: Please don't duplicate your questions while people are trying to answer them.

Comment: this sounds like a cell-reuse issue. please post ur `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: It's not a duplicate question. I figured out how to add the UIView. Now I have a separate issue...

Comment: There is no duplicate of cells. The UIView and the [cell.contentView addSubview:graphView] is only called when indexPath.section == 0 and indexPath.row == 0 as well.

Comment: the code u posted here, is ok — so other some other code must be wrong.

Comment: like what? I did nothing more than add a UIView into a cell. and now when I scroll down in the UITableView there are traces of that UIView in random places and things look really glitchy.

Comment: the only logic answer would be "Give us the code, that is wrong", but as this is not very helpful, i'll traslate it to "... every code, that has something to do with the cell and the graphView"

Comment: a good startingpoint: `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Okay I have posted the tableView:cellforRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @Robert: ok, clear, but it seems like you're trying to solve the same problem ("graphs at the top of each section") which makes me believe that you need the `viewForSectionHeader` solution I posted to your other question, other than using cells for either headers or data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've solved using tags:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    else{
      [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:500] removeFromSuperview];
    }

    ...

    graphView.tag = 500;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:graphView];

   }
```

Comment: Thx a lot.  I used tags the other way.  If the cell had a view with that tag then I didn't add the sub-view to the content view .

Comment: You shouldn't start the `CellIdentifier` variable with a capital letter, use `cellIdentifier` instead.

Answer (score 14):

A table view works slightly differently than you might expect at first. Basically, only the cells that you see are actually loaded into memory. If you think about it, it makes sense - if you had 10,000 items in your table, all loaded into memory, your app is going run out of memory and crash pretty quickly.

When you scroll, your cells are created in real time. The confusing part: your cells aren't created from scratch, instead iOS just takes a cell that has just left the screen and sends it through

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

again. So, the subview you added to your top cell won't be removed when that cell gets reused further down as you scroll. Short answer: make sure you remove/reset the subview in the function above, this way you will 'reset' any used cells that are being reused further down the table view.

Why does iOS do it this way? Efficiency - basically, it is very expensive to create a tableview cell. Finding the width, color, drawing the shape... + lots more takes a lot of cpu power and time. It is far more efficient to reuse cells each time rather than start from scratch.

So reset only the necessary fields of a cell in your cell creation function. This way, you'll have smooth and quick scrolling, but views/properties of your cell will be reset before the cell is reused.

Confusing at first? Yup. But definitely the better way to do it.

Comment: thank you very much. Would you mind explaining how I can "remove/reset the subview in the function above" like you said? So basically I would create the subview prior to the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Then what would I have inside the method?

Comment: Inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, after the "if (cell == nil)" part, reset your subview like so: [cell.contentView.view removeFromSuperview];  But, you also need to create the subview in the case that the cell actually is at the top of the row. So later on, in the same cellForRowAtIndexPath method, have some code to do the following:    if(indexPath.row == 0) {  //create graph view and add it to cell's content view here. }

Comment: so you're saying: if(cell==nil) {[cell.contentView removeFromSuperview];} else { create view and [cell.contentView addSubview:graphView.view]; }? This doesn't work.

Comment: Not quite what I meant. Will write it out as an answer rather than try and put it in a comment!

Answer (score 4):

Ok like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";   

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

//now remove any subview a reused cell might have:   
[cell.contentView.view removeFromSuperview];   
//and in part of the method, you'll need to create the subview if the cell is in the top row.

if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    [cell.contentView.view addSubview:graphView.view];
}
```

It could be slightly different in your case because of the graph view rather than a UIView. But this is definitely the basis of what it should look like.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

This is, as I thought, a cell-reuse issue:

each time, `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` get executed, you add another instance of GraphView. In combination with cell-reuse, where cell-objects get reassigned to other indexPaths, this leads to great trouble.

You should add subviews only inside `if (cell == nil)`.

You'll have to keep track or your GraphViews seperately. Either by adding them to a NSDictionary with the indexPaths as key, or by subclassing UITableViewCell.

Comment: I'm still not certain of what you mean. So add an if statement o see if cell==nil before the cell.contentView addSubview call? And what do you mean regarding tracking GraphViews?