# UITableViewCell Repeating UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am facing a small issue and em banging my head for being not able to solve it…

I have a `UITableView` with **Custom** `UITableViewCell`.. the cell's height is determined on the size of text. when the user taps it, the text is translated and the translated text is appended to it in new line. for making them look separated, I add a `UIView lineView` with width as much as cell's label and `height = 1`

```
 UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(bubbleFrame.origin.x, bubbleFrame.origin.y + bubbleFrame.size.height/2, bubbleFrame.size.width, 1)];
                    lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    lineView.tag = indexPath.row;
                    [cell addSubview:lineView];
```

Everything works fine but when i navigate back to that `viewController` i see that `lineView` misplaced on each cell..

Cant understand why its doing that..

Any help would be appreciated.. Thanks in advance.. [image]

Comment: How do you set the new height of a cell ? Can you show heightForRowAtIndexPath method ?

Comment: Did you remove this UIView before adding it at cellForRow:Atindex ?

Comment: Can you show `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: `heightForRowAtIndexPath` has some calculations but it has nothing to do with it

Comment: the code i added above is in cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: where should i remove it from?

Comment: you should remove it at cellforrowatindexpath before you add the new one because the UITableView dequeue this cell and the view may be added more than once

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim can u provide some code?

Comment: [[cell viewWithTag:SOME_TAG] removeFromSuperView] then add UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(bubbleFrame.origin.x, bubbleFrame.origin.y + bubbleFrame.size.height/2, bubbleFrame.size.width, 1)];
                    lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    lineView.tag = indexPath.row;
                    [cell addSubview:lineView];

Comment: what happens now is the red view is added more than once because you add it each time at cellforrowatindex

Comment: 1st check that if cellheight is maintained properly or not.Then use autolayout properly for the cell and try to add subview on the contentView of UItableViewCell.

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim I tries this but still same issue..

Comment: @Jayaprada height is properly calculated for each cell and maintained properly

Comment: @Ahmed Z, did you check for the autolayout of the cell and give breakpoint to check the frame of lineView?and one more thing mention that if  for example you are hidding the view for one row and unhidding for another row ,mention each and every condition .like          if(indexPath.row == tappedCell){lineview.hidden = no;}else{lineview.hidden = yes;}  
}

Comment: @AhmedZ.It might happen if you scroll the UITableView after tapping on one button???.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some working on the advice of Mustafa Ibrahim, i found another question that had [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9196738/1042240) … so thanks to intropedro's answer problem solved :)

added this with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`

```
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[ChatCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        else{
            [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:500] removeFromSuperview];
        }
```

and changed my lineView code a bit too..

```
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(bubbleFrame.origin.x, bubbleFrame.origin.y + bubbleFrame.size.height/2, bubbleFrame.size.width, 1)];
                    lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    lineView.tag = indexPath.row;
                    [cell addSubview:lineView];
```